# Query to get correponding new col

Tags: sql

Need to get team against team exculing the last x5

```
Teams 
    col1
    X1
    X2
    X3
    X4
    X5

Output Needed :
col1|col2

X1 X2 
X1 X3 
X1 X4 
X1 X5 
X2 X3 
X2 X4 
X2 X5
X3 X4 
X3 X5 
X4 X5
```

SQl query to get above output from a single column

Comment: When you ask an SQL (or NoSQL) database question, you should specify the database you are using. Here in this question, it wouldn't matter but in general it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the combinations using a cross join. ie:

```
Select t1.Col1, t2.Col1
from Teams t1
cross join Teams t2
where t1.Col1 < t2.Col1;
```

Note: Normally you would use the ID, in your sample it didn't exist.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1dbba9658333ab30411c8705f5b01233)

EDIT: Sample with Id usage (Id is comparable like an Int):

```
Select t1.Col1 team1, t2.Col1 team2
from Teams t1
cross join Teams t2
where t1.Id < t2.Id
order by t1.Id, t2.Id;
```

Comment: CROSS JOIN with WHERE, why not do a regular INNER JOIN?

Comment: @jarlh, you might.